# VBA : How to find the last row with data in an excel sheet even if it is hidden?

Tags: vba, excel

**EDIT : Problematic rows are not just hidden, they are filtered**

I'm trying to find a the last row with data in an excel sheet. Everything works fine, except if the last rows with data are hidden by a filter. Then I will always get the last unhidden row with data. I've tried the following :

```
WorkSheet.Cells(WorkSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
```

and :

```
WorkSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=[A1], LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
```

(Also tried LookIn:=xlValues)

But for the same result.

Is it a way to get through this without to have to un-hide/unfilter all the worksheet's rows ?

Comment: Why is the second one not working? Are they hidden or filtered?

Comment: Sorry filtered, I edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WorkSheet.UsedRange()`. But that gives you a *watermark* value insofar that if you expand then contract a workbook then `UsedRange()` does **not** contract correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub FindLastPopulatedRow()
    Dim r As Range, roww As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Not IsEmpty(r) Then
            roww = r.Row
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox roww
End Sub
```

**NOTE**

If you want something fast, swift, speedy, cunning, and agile, then consider something else!